# Accessing Content Provider on Android from PhoneGap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-contentprovider

What is the best way to access the Android Content Provider from within the JavaScript in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write a plugin so you can expose the content provider to the javascript layer.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think I will create a proper plugin (for the community) once this app is done, I took a shortcut and just created another class that extends Activity and just passed the main Context along, if that makes sense